# Problems with downgrading firebase sdk npm package in react-native

Tags: react-native, npm, google-cloud-firestore

Yesterday, I had a problem with my firebase firestore. After searching the solution, I found out that downgrading the version from 7.9.1 to 7.8.2 have to solve the problem

```
npm install firebase@7.8.2
```

and it did. However, after reinstalling the app, the problem appeared again. I think that some sort of npm cache or react-native cache are auto installing or using higher version of firebase. Can someone tell me what maybe potential reasons?

Comment: did you try to clean your npm cache? maybe go to the android folder and gradlew clean to clean the android cache too

Answer (score 0):

I have added this two lines to the `script`-Section of my `package.conf`, to be able to flush all the Cache on my Linux Workstation:

```
"scripts": {
        ...
        "clean-start": "rm -rf ./node_modules && yarn install && watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-map-react-native-packager-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*",
        "kill_MetroBundler": "lsof -i :8081 | grep node | awk '{print $2}'| head -1 | xargs kill",
        ...
    },
```

With it, you only need to run `npm clean-start` and `npm kill_MetroBundler`, before you do `npm start` again.

Hope that helps you out.

**BTW:** *Sometimes* you need to remove your yarn.lock or npm-lockfile to fully remove old dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem was with caches, I ran following commands:

```
rm -rf ./node_modules && yarn install && watchman watch-del-all
```

and the problem was solved